# query regarding getch() input

Tags: c, shell, buffer, getchar, getch

CODE:-

```
char ch,ch1;
ch=getchar();
ch1=getch();
printf("%c\n%c",ch,ch1);
```

When I enter a character during `ch=getchar()`, I have to press enter key, which remains in input buffer.
That enter key is not read by the `ch1=getch()`. 
Why `ch1=getch()` is not reading the remaining enter key?

contradictory to this fact
CODE 2:-

```
char ch,ch1;
ch=getch();
ch1=getch();
printf("%c\n%c",ch,ch1);
```

When I press a arrow key which produces two outputs, the first output is stored in `ch` and the second output is stored in `ch1`.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C input functions only start processing what you type in when you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Every key you press adds a character to the system buffer (`shell`), but only when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> these characters are **MOVED** to C standard buffer.

So after `ch = getchar();` the C buffer contains a newline and the system buffer is empty. (`getch()`, which isn't a standard function, will read the system buffer).

---

In the second example, `getch()` function returns multiple keycodes for a special key (`getch()` isn't standardized and these codes might vary).

E.g.

- MinGW  / Visual C++ (`conio.h`): two keycodes. Either 0x00 or 0xE0 first and then the code identifying the key that was pressed.
- GCC (`termios.h`): three keycodes. First *'\033'* (ESC), then *'['*, last the code identifying the key pressed.

Anyway using only `getch()` you're reading all the characters in the system buffer (without forcing a transfer to the C standard buffer).